# Get a list of all users whose email address begins with sh followed by any 6 characters

Tags: active-directory, powershell, directory

I want to lost down all users whose email addresses begins with sh followed by any other 6 characters.

Sh******@abc.com

How can I achieve that using active directory users and computers or Get-ADUser or some other means?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

So you are looking for mail addresses with a fixed length of 16 characters (Sh******@abc.com). Starting with sh is covered by Powershells `like` operator. 
This should work:

`Get-ADUser -Filter {EMailAddress -like "sh*"} -Properties EmailAddress| Where {$_.EMailAddress.length -eq 16}`